# In Django the media file is not getting created when user uploads a picture

Tags: python, django

i guess the ImageField(upload_to="pics") parameter must create a folder in the project directory with name as 'pics' when user chooses or uploads a media(image). But its not working.Even the 'pics' folder is not created. The image name is only getting stored in the database but when i fetch the image it cannot find the image. Please Help

will `data=tableOne.objects.get(phone=phone1)` fetch my image from database ?

my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

my project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my models.py:

```
class tableOne(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
propic = models.ImageField(upload_to="pics")
```

my views.py:

```
def imageupload(request):
name=request.POST.get('name')
email=request.POST.get('email')
phone=request.POST.get('phone')
password=request.POST.get('password')
p=request.POST.get('picture')
data=tableOne(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,password=password,propic=p)
data.save()
return HttpResponse("Image inserted")
```

my views.py where i am fetching my image:

```
def login(request):
name1=request.POST['name1']
phone1=request.POST['phone1']
request.session['details']=phone1
data=tableOne.objects.get(phone=phone1)
log_name=data.name
if(name1==log_name):
    return render(request,"nextpage.html",{ 'user' : data } )
```

template where i am uploading my details:

```
{% load static %}
```

```
    <form method="POST" action="imageupload">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="file" name="picture"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <!-- loging in to fetch image -->
    <form method="POST" action="login">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name1"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone1"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>

</body>
```

template where i want to post my image(nextpage.html):

```
<img src="{{ user.propic.url }}">
```

Comment: try with request.FILES.get('picture')

Comment: not working image not saving in DB

Comment: post your template also

Comment: given my both template

Comment: <form method="POST" action="{% url 'url_name' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">, add this

Comment: its not working,media is unable to create 'pics' folder,this is showing :                  /media/IMG_20191227_180527_427.jpg

Comment: this is working if i use the admin pannel but if a user uploads then its not working

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your main `urls.py`,

```
 ...
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

 ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: do i have to add this in project urls.py or app urls.py ?

Comment: project urls.py